# Getting a React source code to production with Digital Ocean

Tags: reactjs, nginx, npm, webpack, devops

I'm trying to practice devOps and thought of deploying my software to a cloud provisioned machine.

**Source code**: https://github.com/tj/frontend-boilerplate

**package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --history-api-fallback --hot --inline --progress --colors --port 3000",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors"
  }
```

In my local machine I would have to:

1. Clone the front end repo (react)
2. then do `npm install`
3. then do `npm start`

I would then be able to see it running in my browser in the address `localhost:3000`

I tried to replicate the same scenario in an ubuntu machine hosted by Digital Ocean.

1. `ssh` into the machine
2. Clone front end repo
3. `npm install` and `npm start`

I then tried to go to `mycloudmachinesip:3000` but I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (site cannot be reached)

How do I deploy my front end app to my remote machine correctly?

## UPDATE

I tried looking for answers on the internet and found that i have to install and spin up an nginx server.

So running `npm run build` would produce a static directory and a compressed `.js` file. I then pointed my root (nginx server config) to that static directory.

this is how my server config (I don't have a domain name):

```
server {
    listen <myremotemachineip>:80;
    root /www/frontend-boilerplate/static;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
    }
}
```

however I still get see the "Welcome to nginx" message when i visit my ip in the browser. Where did I go wrong?